# What's the fastest way for Longest Prefix Match algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, trie

I am looking for an algorithm that does a fast lookup on the longest prefix match that can be used to match an input number(between 6 and 16 digits long) to a large set of prefixes (about 200k entries) similar to matching an IP address to a set of prefixes in a routing table. Insertion and deletion speed are not of concern since the lookup speed is the ultimate goal. I wonder if a suffix tree algorithm is the only option for me.